# How to install linux on mac mini 2010

Tags: 14.04, mac

I have a mac mini mid-2010 model

I wiped out OS X and installed ubuntu 14.04 64 bit mac. Except, it's really buggy. It freezes a lot and I have to restart. But someones it will work really smoothly for a few minutes. Is it the OS or is it my computer? If its the OS, what distro of Linux should I get for my computer then?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the operating system that's the problem, try installing an older version of Ubuntu and see if that works.  I also have a mid 2010 Mac Mini that's currently running OS X Mavericks, and I've been attempting to install Ubuntu through various methods (LiveCD method, bootable USB, and dual booting) and they all never work.  What would happen is that I would get Ubuntu to load at start up but then it would take a long time to actually load into the operating system, I also have this unusual issue with my monitor that isn't present in OS X (Or Windows for that matter) where Ubuntu seems to lag and the screen flashes (This happened the first time on dual booting).  In my opinion, if you want to try out a Linux distribution, do so on a PC, Macs are very close sourced as far as hardware and software goes, so even if you got it to work, you probably wouldn't have a lot of options. I know this response is a few months late and you've probably either got it to work, or gave up on it... but I felt my response was relevant, as someone who also owns a mid 2010 Mac Mini. My advise would be to reinstall OS X and leave it at that, and if you really want to try out Linux, call Apple to see what they say because as far as operating systems go, Mac really wasn't meant for anything but OS X.